# How to eliminate strings from a list given that those strings are not included in another string and put them in a formula?

Tags: r, string, list, vector

I have a list of strings and another string that contains a subset of those strings. I need to substract the subset of strings from the first list, and then I need to put the output in a R formula.

For example:

```
total <- c("Blue", "Black", "Green","Red", "White", "Yellow")
small <- c("Blue", "Red")

 Output <- total - small
```

What I got:

```
Error in Output : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

What was the expected result:
[1] "Black" "Green" "White" "Yellow"

Then I want to separate the elements of Output by a + and put this in a R formula:

```
myFormula <- as.formula(paste(Output, sep=" + "))
```

Comment: something like `reformulate(setdiff(total,small))` ?

Comment: Thanks @Moody_Mudskipper!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the `response` argument if you want an empty LHS:

```
reformulate(setdiff(total, small), response = "y")
## y ~ Black + Green + White + Yellow
```